# Can ngResource pass nested object into GET query?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2, ngresource

I am using ngResource to communicate with my Web API.
I want to send a search request to my WebAPI controller but the object is not   flat:

```
var searchRequest = {
   query: "hotel",
   page: 1,
   price:
   {
      min: 1000,
      max: 2500
   }
}
```

And my controller takes a SearchRequest parameter with the same structure as sent object so the request should look like

```
http://localhost/api/search?query=hotel&page=1&price.min=1000&price.max=2500
```

However, ngResource `$resource.query(searchRequest)` is sending this:

```
http://localhost/api/search?query=hotel&page=1price=%7B%22min%22:1000,%22max%22:2500%7D
```

Answer (score 0):

If it was me I would change this to use an OData attributed endpoint that returns an IQueryable.  Then use breeze.js on the frontend to generate the queries.  Have a look at these:

https://ovaismehboob.wordpress.com/2014/01/18/adding-queryable-support-to-asp-net-web-api-controller-action-methods/

http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/server-odata.html

I could be wrong but I don't think this will work with nested queries.  Another solution might be to flatten the query and then use a linq projection or automapper projection to query the data source but that would depend on what you linq provider can handle